# ROS Service and Message

Tags: python, c++, robotics, ros

I am using ROS system and I am a beginner.
I came across Service and Message (srv and msgs) in ROS. From the ros wiki, I manage to understand like msgs are used to define the type of message been passed and service is about request and response. Please correct me if I got this wrong.

Nevertheless, I am unable to understand when to use them. I thought that maybe it would be useful if I have modules written in C++ and other Processing Modules in Python than perhaps I can use srv and msgs for communicating between the 2 modules. However, than ROS also have publisher and subscriber system which could be used instead?

Secondly, when we use srv than only we need to define the msgs or either can be independently be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, let me point you here:

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29

It's the first example given by `Ros` [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials).

Publishers and subscribers are entities used to achieve node intercommunication. Publishers post messages to a channel, while subscribers listen to such channels to acquire messages possibly sent by publishers. Publishers post to channel using messages and which hold different kind of data depending on what is trying to be achieved. Subscribers take these messages and automatically execute a `callback function` to achieve something useful with the data.

Now let me point you here:

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28c%2B%2B%29

It is a similar example, but this time, services are used to achieve communication. The things with messages is that, once the node publishes a message, the whole communication thing is over and the node continues with the rest of its job. On the other hand, client (they use services) communicate with servers; they publish a message to a server, and then wait for a response by that server.

**Examples:**

1. Imagine you have two nodes: the first one creates and publishes random int numbers and the second one takes these numbers and publishes their squares on the screen. You can imagine that we only need messages there: the first node doesn't have to wait for an answer from the second node. The first node will use a publisher to provide the integers, while the second node will use a subscriber to get those integers and execute a function which will post their squares.
2. Imagine you want to implement a tic-tac-toe game with ROS: now you'd like to have 3 nodes: the 2 of them are identical and they represent the two players, while the third one would be the AI handling the board. Now the AI publishes the board to a player, but it also needs to wait for answer; that answer would be the move that current player would choose. That's why services would have to be used here.

If you make sure you understand a simple program with messages and a simple program with services, then you can expand your knowledge by creating examples, like the one presented above. Only then will you be able to fully grasp it with full detail.

Comment: As a third example, a service may also be used, to reduce unnecessary communication effort. For example a path planner might not subscribe to a map topic, but rather only request a map when it is needed (in this case, the message to the server does not contain any content). The advantage is, that the new map has only to be sent and processed, if it is actually needed.

Answer (score 1):

ROS publishing/subscribing is many-to-many (in terms of connections) and one-way 
transport of data. It's asynchronous, meaning your code will not block and you will need to implement a callback function that will act asynchronously.

ROS services, on the other hand, are synchronous and one-to-one two-way transport of data, meaning the client blocks and waits for a response from the server.

Think about the following cases:

1. Think of a robot and a simulator with the robot's model. The simulator needs to update the robot's model in real-time (as the robot in the real world changes configuration, the simulator needs to update the model to reflect that change such that the robot model in the simulator is always up-to-date with the current configuration of the real robot).
2. Think of a node that controls a robot cashier. This node requires to detect a customer using the robot's camera to start the interaction.

In the first case, you will need a publishing/subscribing model because the simulator will need data to flow in real-time while doing something else. So the robot will publish its joint values to a topic and the simulator will subscribe to that topic with a callback function that will update the robot model in the simulator in real-time asynchronously.

In the second case, however, you don't want a node to constantly check for a customer and is not something you want to do constantly. You know in your program logic when you need to detect a customer. When you first start your node, you know that you need to block and wait for a customer to come in. It's more appropriate here to use a service. When you want to detect a customer you send a request to the server (and as a result your program blocks waiting for a response). The server will use the camera to detect a customer (using some detection algorithm) and will respond accordingly back to you.

Generally speaking, you will use publishing/subscribing when you need data to flow constantly and you want to act on these data asynchronously, and services when you need a specific calculation to happen synchronously.